# Subdivision via poset maps and pullback

Tags: co.combinatorics, gt.geometric-topology, combinatorial-topology

In the following, all posets and complexes are assumed to be finite.
For a poset $P$ denote by $|P|$ its geometric realization or nerve (i.e. forming the order complex and taking its geometric realization $-$ a functor from the category of posets to topological spaces).

Call an order preserving map $f:P\to Q$ between posets a *($PL$-)subdivision map* if for all $x\leq y \in Q$
we have ($PL$-)homeomorphism $h_y:|f^{-1}(Q_{\leq y})| \to |Q_{\leq y}|$ such that $h_x = h_y|_{f^{-1}(Q_{\leq x})}$.
This is equivalent to the existence of a ($PL$-)homeomorphism $h:|P|\to|Q|$ which restricts
to homeomorphisms $h_x:|f^{-1}(Q_{\leq x})|\to |Q_{\leq x}|$ for all $x\in Q$ (of course, this h ist not the geometric realization $|f|$ of the poset map $f$).

For example, for a poset $P$ denote by $P^{(1)}$ its derived poset which consists of all chains $(x_0 < x_1 < \ldots <x_k)$ in $P$ ordered by inclusion (i.e. the face poset of the associated simplicial order complex).
Then the natural map $\pi:P^{(1)}\to P, (x_0 < x_1 < \ldots <x_k) \mapsto x_k$ is a subdivision map.
More generally, if we have a polyhedral complex $K$ and a subdivision $L$ in the geometric sense, i.e. the underlying polyhedra are the same and each $c \in L$ is contained in a unique minimal $c' \in K$, then the map $\mathscr{F}(L) \to \mathscr{F}(K), c \mapsto c'$, where $\mathscr{F}(-)$ denotes the *face poset* of a complex, is a subdivision map in the above sense.

Another fact: if $U \subset Q$ is an order ideal and $f:P\to Q$ is a subdivision map, then the restriction (or pullback) $f':f^{-1}(U)\to U$ is again a subdivision map.

My questions:

1. Is there a good reference where such subdivision maps have been studied in this general poset context?
2. What are sufficient conditions which ensure that the pullback of a subdivision map is again a subdivision map? In particular for inclusions of subposets $U \hookrightarrow Q$ which are not order ideals?

Regarding question 2) the cases which I have in mind is a subdivided cell complex via $f:P\to Q$ which is also a PL-manifold and $U\hookrightarrow Q$ which yields $|U|\subseteq |Q|$ a ($PL$-)submanifold.
I have the feeling this should be connected to transversality properties.

And here is a simple non-example for 2):
take as poset $Q:a<c, b<c$ and $a,b$ not comparable, and as poset $P:a<c_1,d<c_1,d<c_2,b<c_2$ and no other relations. Define $f:P\to Q$ by
$f^{-1}(a)=\{a\},f^{-1}(b)=\{b\},f^{-1}(c)=\{d,c_1,c_2\}$,
i.e. $f$ is the derived subdivision map for the face poset of the $1$-simplex. Then for $U=\{c\}\subseteq Q$ the pulled back map $f':f^{-1}(c)\to \{c\}$ is apparently not a subdivision map anymore.

Here is another example.
[image]
In the first case, the pulled back map is not a subdivision map, but in the second case it is.